# Is there a way I can take user input and make it into a file?

Tags: bash

I am not able to find a way to make bash create a file with the same name as the file the user dragged into the terminal.

```
        read -p 'file: ' file
        if [ "$file" -eq "" ]; then
        cd desktop
        mkdir  
        fi
```

I am trying to make this part of the script take the name of the file they dragged in so for example /Users/admin/Desktop/test.app cd into it copy the "contents" file make another folder with the same name so test.app for this example and then paste the contents file into that folder and delete the old file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your .app example, I assume you are using MacOS. Therefore you will need to test this script yourself since I don't have MacOS, but I think it should be doing what you want. Execute it as `bash script.sh` and it will give you your desired directory `test.app/contents` in the current working directory.

```
#! /bin/bash

read -rp 'file: ' file
if [ -e "$file" ];  then
  if [ -e "$file"/contents ]; then
    base=$(basename "$file")
    mkdir "$base"
    cp -R "$file"/contents "$base"
    rm -rf "$file"
  else
    echo "The specified file $file has no directory 'contents'."
  fi
else
  echo "The specified file $file does not exist."
fi
```

Comment: Maybe also bail out with a useful error message if `"$file"/contents` does not exist.

Comment: You are very smart, my friend and I have been working on an exploit framework to get around school blocking things and making a script do it only in 7 lines of code compared to our 30 (He worked on it after I posted) is impressive.